# Разница путей в URL

Tags: html, ссылки, пути

**Есть несколько ссылок:**

1. `<a href="/path/">Link1</a>`
2. `<a href="/path">Link2</a>`
3. `<a href="./path/">Link3</a>`
4. `<a href="./path">Link4</a>`

В чем разница? Я тестировал, но ничего не понял.

P.S Я знаю, что на сервере есть такое понятие как корневой каталог, к нему обращаются через `/` как от главного и также это применяется для разделение каталогов. Так же есть `../` используется чтобы подняться вверх по иерархии.

Comment: http://htmlbook.ru/samhtml/ssylki/absolyutnye-i-otnositelnye-ssylki

Comment: @ElenaSemenchenko Там нет на это ответа!

Answer (score 0):

В каталоге есть всегда 2 каталога: `.` и `..`.Две точки это ниже,а одна это текущий.То есть разница между ссылками есть только если ты пишешь слеш в конце и как ты уже заметил то он означает поднятие на 1 каталог по иерархиию.

Comment: `../ - на каталог выше`,`./ - текущий каталог`. Но я так и не понял отличие слешей в конце! Разница между `path/` и `path` какая?

Comment: @MaximPro Разница path/ и path зависит от сайта. У кого-то нет разницы, кто-то выпишет ошибку. Если path представляет каталог на сайте, то часто автоматически добавляется /. На самом деле ещё автоматически подставляется ещё какой-нибудь index.html в обоих случаях

Comment: @Sergey то есть это конкретно зависит от настройки сервера?

Comment: @MaximPro Ну да. Было время, лично курил мануалы, чтобы мой сервер понимал `path` как `path/`. Мне тоже не охота лишний знак писать, тем более, что для его набора требуется две руки (или хотя бы два пальца:). Правда это только на русской раскладке.

Comment: @Sergey У меня стоит ванильная сборка xampp и `path/` и `path` понимаются одинаково =) Я вот именно по этой причине спросил, да и к тому же большинство сайтов это интерпретируют одинаково.